# Help with understanding this linear functionals argument

Tags: functional-analysis

Now I have come across a few proofs that all involved a similar argument involving linear functionals and I don't understand how it works. Can someone please help me understand it? The argument goes like this:

If $f(a) = f(b)$ for all $f \in A^\ast$ ($a,b \in A$) where $A$ is a Banach space it follows that $a=b$.

Of course for any linear map $T$, if $Ta = Tb$ then $Ta - Tb = T(a-b)=0$. This doesn't imply $a-b=0$ since the map $T=0$ is continuous and linear. Therefore the  step in the argument that I am missing is: why if it's true for *all* $T$ then indeed $a-b=0$ is deducible.

Answer (score 3):

This follow from the Hahn-Banach extension theorem, which can be stated as follows:

> **Theorem**. Given a normed space $X$, a closed subspace $U \subseteq X$ and a linear continuous $u^* \in U^*$. Then there is an extension $x^* \in X^*$ of $u^*$ with the same norm, that is $x^*|_U = u^*$ and $\def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}\norm{u^*} = \norm{x^*}$.

From this fact, we can deduce the following:

> **Corollary**. Let $X$ be a normed space and $x \in X-\{0\}$. Then there is an $x^* \in X^*$ with $x^*(x) \ne 0$.

*Proof*. Define $U := {\rm span}\, \{x\}$, and $u^*(\lambda x) = \lambda\norm x$.Then $u^*\in U^*$ and $\norm{u^*} = 1$. Let $x^*$ be a Hahn-Banach extension, then $x^* \in X^*$ and $x^*(x) = u^*(x) = \norm{x}\ne 0$.

If now $x,y\in X$ are different points, then $x-y\ne 0$, and the above Corollary gives an $f \in X^*$ with $f(x-y) \ne 0$, that is $f(x) \ne f(y)$. 
Hence if $f(x) =f(y)$ holds for all $f \in X^*$, we must have $x=y$.

Comment: I'm sorry for taking so long. Could it be that the $U$ in the theorem does not necessarily have to be closed?

Comment: And I have one more question: you define $u^\ast(\lambda x) = \lambda \|x\|$. I believe this is not linear since $u^\ast (x + y ) \le \|x\| + \|y\|$. No? I would like to suggest the following fix: If $\mathbb K$ denotes the base field of the normed space then fix any $k \in \mathbb K \setminus \{0\}$ and define $u^\ast (\lambda x) = \lambda k$. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: Sorry, your map *is* linear! But I believe my suggestions works also. One should be able to map $x$ to any fixed scalar.

Comment: Is it okay for me to edit your answer and delete ''closed''? @martini